# Fuzzy search on a multivalued field

Tags: solr

Just wanted to check if it is possible to do a fuzzy lookup on a multivalued valued field.

The multivalued field is defined as follows:

```
<field name="all_fields" type="textSuggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
  <copyField source="level_number" dest="all_fields"/>
  <copyField source="flat_number" dest="all_fields"/>
  <copyField source="number_first" dest="all_fields"/>
  <copyField source="number_last" dest="all_fields"/>
  <copyField source="number_street_name" dest="all_fields"/> 

 <fieldType name="textSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([|]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\n]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>  
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The data looks like as following:

```
 {
    "number_first":"11",
    "all_fields":["11",
      "2",
      "ROSS|ST||FOREST LODGE|NSW|2037|",
      ""],
    "flat_number":"2",
    "number_street_name":"ROSS|ST||FOREST LODGE|NSW|2037|",
    "text_suggest":"ROSS|ST||FOREST LODGE|NSW|2037|",
    "number_last":"",
    "number_street_name_full":"ROSS|STREET||FOREST LODGE|NSW|2037|",
    "text_suggest_full":"ROSS|STREET||FOREST LODGE|NSW|2037|",
    "_version_":1790007757222445056}
```

Finally, the suggester definition is as follows:

```
<lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">all_fields</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textSuggest</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="maxEdits">1</str>
      <str name="storeDir">fuzzy_suggestions</str>
```

Trying to search using the query:

```
http://localhost:8986/solr/testcore/suggest?suggest.dictionary=fuzzySuggester&suggest.q=all_fields:11
```

I don't get anything back.

Any suggestions where I might be making a mistake?